# Avoid small tag in `align` environment wrapped around `small`

Tags: math-mode, align, fontsize, tags

I am working in an `align` environment, where I have a long equation. To make it fit within the line width, I wrap a `small` environment around the `align` one:

```
\begin{small}
\begin{align}
...
\end{align}
\end{small}
```

The problem I have is that not only is the size of the equation reduced, *but also the size of the tag number at the end of the line*, a feature I want to avoid.

**How to have a math environment in small font size except for the equation tag?**

Comment: Why not just break it into multiple lines. There might be ways of adjusting the content without having to adjust the size. Can you provide more context in the form of a minimal example?

Comment: @Werner it's actually a long fraction, so breaking it down into multiple lines would read awkwardly here.

Comment: How about defining some components as variables to shorten the fraction... just a suggestion.

Comment: do you mean you have small around align? I can't see how you can have alugn around small? small long fractions hard to read consider setting as *a/b  where a=..... and b=...^

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes that's what I mean - I edited the question.

Comment: In general it is never a good idea to resort to scaling down the font of a displayed equation. Rephrase at least for the sake of your readers.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw: How about [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/M4jpPzHc) (using `\scalebox{<num>}{<stuff>}` from [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx))?

Comment: @Werner I am getting two errors when I use this: `\mathrm allowed only in math mode` (I have a command `mathrm` in my equation), and multiple instances of `Missing $ inserted` and `Extra }, or forgotten $`. No error when I comment out the `scalebox`.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw: The second argument of `\scalebox` (the stuff you want to scale) is set in text mode, not math mode. You'll note in [my example code](https://pastebin.com/raw/M4jpPzHc) I use `\scalebox{0.8}{$\displaystyle ... $}` to reset the contents in "display math mode", since `align` does that.

Comment: If you're wrapping `small` around `align`, check the baseline spacing of the paragraph above the display.  If you don't have a blank line before `\begin{small}`, the baselines in that paragraph will be appropriate for `small` (that paragraph doesn't wrap until the display ends).  But if you have a blank line between paragraph and display, you should check for  a page break and may have to suppress it; and you will certainly have to adjust for excess `\abovedisplayskip`.

Answer (score 2):

The equation tag is typeset using `\normalfont` which invokes the eponymous hook.  You can just add `\normalsize` to that hook to also reset the font size.

This requires a fairly new LaTeX since the hook management was only introduced recently.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{small}
  \begin{align}
    ... \tag{small tag}
  \end{align}
\end{small}

\begin{small}
  \AddToHook{normalfont}[normalsize]{\normalsize}
  \begin{align}
    ... \tag{normal tag}
  \end{align}
  \RemoveFromHook{normalfont}[normalsize]
\end{small}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding `\normalsize` to `\normalfont` would be a reasonable update to `amsmath` (it's more often wanted than not, and if it's not wanted, would be easy to patch).  Trickier is avoiding the effects on the preceding paragraph; see my comment to the question.  (That effect drives competent copyeditors bonkers.)  It would improve your answer to show a multiline paragraph above the display.